# A quick way to hack function calls in C

Tags: c, assembly, stack

I have an existing codebase which  is written in C. What I want to achieve is to change the function call order in run time. For ex., assume func_A  calls func_B . What I want is that  based on some conditions whenever func_B is called, instead of executing the code inside func_B , we should execute func_C instead.

```
func_C (arg1,arg2)
{
    return 1;
}
func_B (arg1,arg2)
{
   return 0;
}
func_A ()
{
    /*The code is writen to always call func_B*/
    return func_B(arg1,arg2)
}



main()
{
  int result;
  result = func_A ();
  //here result = 0 as expected.
  /*Do some magic*/
  result = func_A ()
  //result should be 1
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in C language by doing some program execution/stack manipulation ? I don't mind writing Assembly code as well. The goal is that I shouldn't change func_A,func_B and func_C

Comment: There is no `func_C` in your example, but why simply don't use function pointers? `static  int (*func_B_ptr)(arg1,arg2) = func_B;`, replace `func_B` calls with `func_B_ptr` and then assign `func_C` to `func_B_ptr`.

Comment: CORRECTED the names slightly. I can't use function pointers because then I need to change func_B and func_C accordingly. The goal is to acheive this WITHOUT changing func_A and func_B

Comment: If you have the C source code, change the C source code. Why would you want to dig into assembly if you can do it comfortably from C?

Comment: @abelenky Thanks for pointing out the error. I've corrected it.

Comment: Why?! Just why! Either you have source code you can patch in C, or you have a binary you have to patch in bytecode.

Comment: For Unit testing. In some cases, I want to execute existing function.. In other cases I want to verify the call arguments and in some other cases I want to verify the return value, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @UtkarshKumar So write a function which will perform the testing and will call the functions required, based on whatever condition(s) you have in your mind.

Comment: What you mentioned is not possible.. Because, when I cal func_A it ALWAYS calls func_B. I want to make a change to the call order, either automatically or during runtime.

Comment: The C language provides no way to do this without altering the existing functions.  If `func_B()` were in a shared library, however, then there would be dynamic linker tricks you could play to achieve an equivalent of your desired effect.

Comment: for testing purposes it helps to improve your design to better use interfaces and implementations of them given through dependency injection. Then you can easily set up various test cases of method A using at one time implementation B, and at other time using implementation B_xx (maybe extended from B directly). Classic procedural A call B is difficult to test, almost impossible to achieve such per-sub-function granularity and configuration.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Could you please tell me more about dynamic-linker tricks to acheive this ? Any references in mind ?

Comment: The details are system dependent.  On some systems, including Linux, you can use the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to preload a library containing an alternative implementation of `func_B()`, that will then, under the right circumstances, be used instead of the usual `func_B()`.  Research `LD_PRELOAD`  for more information.

Comment: wonderful !! This should work (at least get me started). Can I not mark this as the accepted answer ? :)

Answer (score 0):

A "quick" way is to use `if-else` or `switch` statements to call different functions based on some condition. :)

```
func_A ()
{
    if(condition)
    {    
        /*The code is writen to always call func_B*/
        return func_B(arg1,arg2);
    }
    else
    {
        /*The code is writen to always call func_C*/
        return func_C(arg1,arg2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But like I mentioned The goal is that I shouldn't change func_A,func_B and func_C

Comment: @UtkarshKumar You can not execute a function without calling it! There are various methods to call the function. e.g. C function call, through function pointer or asm by loading the appropriate registers for that matter. But you have to *call* the function! And to do that you need to write the code which will change the existing function definition(s)

Comment: Let's talk about registers more... Do you know any way to manipulate the registers so the the call order would change ? Is there a way to do it inside function A ? I can use __cig_profile_enter() to hack it..

Comment: @UtkarshKumar There is no need to "manipulate" the registers. A function call in asm involves loading appropriate registers. Can't seem to remember the exact processor, which BTW depends on machine architecture. A quick Google search pointed me to this http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/asm/calling.html

Comment: BTW loading the registers to call the C function is a low level underlying detail of an explicit C function call. In any case you have to change the code to reflect your intent.

Answer (score 0):

You could route the calls via writable,  global function pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*func_A)(void);
int (*func_B)(void);
int (*func_C)(void);

 int
func_C_ ()
{
    return 1;
}
int
func_B_ ()
{
   return 0;
}
int
func_A_ ()
{
    /*The code is writen to always call func_B*/
    return func_B();
}
int (*func_A)(void) = func_A_;
int (*func_B)(void) = func_B_;
int (*func_C)(void) = func_C_;


int main()
{
  int result;
  result = func_A ();
  printf("%d\n", result);
  //here result = 0 as expected.
  /*Do some magic*/
  func_B = func_C;

  result = func_A ();
  printf("%d\n", result);
  //result should be 1
}
```

https://ideone.com/Oz2JyQ

That's rather quick and easy. Editing opcodes live probably won't be (I too would like to see this done through live opcode editing) .